# Modifying an element in min-heap and rebuild heap in sublinear time

Tags: c++, algorithm, heap, min-heap

Suppose I build a min heap:

```
std::vector<int> h;
...
std::make_heap(h.begin(), h.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

Then I modify an arbitrary heap element:

```
h[7] = 0;
```

The heap property is then broken after this modification so I cannot rely on `std::heap_push` or `std::heap_pop` any longer.

I know I can use `std::make_heap` on `h` again to rebuild the heap but it takes linear time.

Is there any way to modify an element of the min heap and rebuild the heap in sublinear time?

Comment: Yes, but you need to know the index of that element which can be done. Then you can modify an element in `O(logN)` time.